# infinitve and be verb

Tags: infinitives

I wrote a letter to have our scheduled meeting be moved"

is "to have our scheduled meeting be moved" infinitive clause? what is meaning of "to have"?

why use "be moved"? is it passive voice?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The causative with "have" doesn't call for "be". "I wrote a letter to have our scheduled meeting moved." https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/the-causative

Comment: so adding "be" is incorrect?